# RedHat OpenJDK 8 applets in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet, jnlp

I'm evaluating moving from Oracle Java to OpenJDK for desktop machines. A requirement we have is being able to still execute applets from an IE11 browser (I know, it's bad but a couple government sites still use them we have to work with).

After installing the RedHat OpenJDK 8 32-bit (and checking the box for Web Start support - which uses iced tea), JNLP files work fine, but applets do not. It doesn't look like any accelerator/plugin was added to IE.

Fairly new to the OpenJDK in a Windows/desktop environment, so may be something simple I'm missing.

Any idea on how to get applets to work using the OpenJDK 8 32-bit on Windows machines with IE11?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this from other sources?

Comment: Nope. After much research, I’ve determined the best course of action is to stick with Oracle JRE for any machines needing applet utilization. My hope is folk move their products off applets soon now that they are officially dead...